# How to get the source code for the trunk or a certain branch for projects hosted in github

Tags: github

How to get the source code for the trunk or a certain branch for projects hosted in github. Is it available in a zip or tar.gz format.

I am aware that I could check out a branch / tag and zip the source code. But I am curious to know if it is automated and is available as part of the release cycle.

Note: This is usually available for projects hosted in Apache Software Foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible: go to github.com// and click on download. You should be able to download the source in .zip and .tar.gz formats.

This works for both branches and tags, you just have to change your current branch/tag.